# What do return -1, 1, and 0 mean in this Javascript code?

Tags: javascript

Here is the context:

```
function compare (value1, value2) {
    if(value1 < value2) {
        return -1;
    } else if (value1 > value2) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

var values = [0, 6, 8, 5];
values.sort(compare);
alert(values); // 0,5,6,8
```

does `-1` return the last argument? Like when using `-1` in an array?

Comment: Accessing arguments by index looks like `arguments[0]`, and it won't accept negative numbers.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, -1, 0, and 1 in a comparison function are used to tell the caller how the first value should be sorted in relation to the second one.  -1 means the first goes before the second, 1 means it goes after, and 0 means they're equivalent.

The `sort` function uses the comparisons in the function you pass it to sort the function.  For instance, if you wanted to sort in reverse order, you could make line 3 `return 1;` and line 5 `return -1`.

Answer (score 14):

The `sort` method takes an optional comparison function that determines the resulting sort order based on the following:

- if its return value is less than zero, then sort `value1` to a lower index than `value2`
- if its return value is zero, then leave the indices of `value1` and `value2` unchanged with respect to each other
- if its return value is greater than zero, then sort `value1` to a higher index than `value2`

Note that given these rules, it's possible to shorten your comparison function to the following:

```
function compare(value1, value2) {
    return value1 - value2;
}
```

Comment: Honestly, I think this answer deserves more upvotes than mine.

Comment: @harrison_m: Well, you're free to delete yours. ;p

Answer (score 5):

`-1` means that `value1` is less than `value2`

`0` means that `value1` is equal to `value2`

`1` means that `value1` is greater than `value2`

Answer (score -1):

```js
// filter in array
function filterDataByInput(){
    let searchInput = document.getElementById('searchInput').value;
    let result = userDetails.filter(function (value){
        return value.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchInput.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    });
    console.log(result)
}
```

-1 search from **a**bcd
0 search from a**b**cd
1 search from ab**c**d